# Is there a way to see the actual change performed by the entry in the change log?

Tags: contacts, logs

The change log as it stands seems pretty pointless if you only can see that someone has changed something (anything) for a contact.

Is there any way to see *what* was changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can switch on the advanced logging in the Administer/System Settings/Misc[image], that will show you far more detailed logging. I expect it will impact your performance, so it is probably worthwhile to test it first.

Comment: Personal testimony: The adv logging didn't impact our performance really, but it did impact our database size. The logging tables got quite large relatively quickly. You may want to download/dump the logging tables on a regular basis.

Comment: if your tables get too large, intelligent pruning rather than dumping will be needed if you want to be able to see what was changed.  The log tables record the new state, not the changes. When you prune, you will need to keep the most recent entry for each contact or there won't be any base data to compare the new state with when you try to look at a change log entry.